# How to pass a variable in `redirect(url_for())`

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to pass a variable while redirecting to another URL, with flask, in python, and am getting `name var not defined`.

This is what Im doing:

```
@app.route('/')
def root():
    delay = randint(0, 5)
    time.sleep(delay)
    return redirect(url_for('first_hop', delay=delay))
```

This seems to be the way to pass the variable, based on other answers.

```
@app.route('/first_hop')
def first_hop():
    x = delay
    print(delay)
    return redirect(url_for('second_hop'))
```

But here, I don't know how to get it. Do I have to make the variable global?

The error is below.

> NameError: name 'delay' is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass arguments into redirect(url\_for()) of Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954122/how-can-i-pass-arguments-into-redirecturl-for-of-flask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `first_hop`, the parameters can be obtained using `request.args.get('delay')`.

```
@app.route('/first_hop')
def first_hop():
    x = request.args.get('delay')
    print(x)
    return redirect(url_for('second_hop'))
```

Comment: thank you! I had checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057191/redirect-while-passing-arguments, which didn't work.