# Flask-wtforms Redirect on Form Submission and Pass Variables

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am struggling to figure out why I am unable to pass variables to my redirected url. I have attempted the suggestions in the following questions, but for some reason they are not working.

[redirect while passing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057191/redirect-while-passing-arguments)

[How can I pass arguments into redirect(url_for()) of Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954122/how-can-i-pass-arguments-into-redirecturl-for-of-flask)

The only thing I can think of is that it is because I am using flask-wtforms to validate the form before the redirect. I haven't seen much in way of answers/suggestions for this scenario. So here I am.

```
    @app.route('/quiz/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def quiz():
        form = Quiz()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            q1_answer = 'North'
            return redirect(url_for('result', q1_answer=q1_answer))
        return render_template('quiz.html', form=form)

    @app.route('/result/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def result():
        q1_correct_answer = request.args.get('q1_answer')
        return render_template('result.html', q1_correct_answer=q1_correct_answer)
```

The redirect works the way it should. The 'result' url and its corresponding template are rendered. I just can't get the variable (q1_answer) to pass. My template always returns a value of None. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use it

```
@app.route('/quiz/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def quiz():

    form = Quiz()
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        q1_answer = 'North'
        return redirect(url_for('result', q1_answer=q1_answer))
    return render_template('quiz.html', form=form)

@app.route('/result/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def result(q1_answer):

    return render_template('result.html', q1_correct_answer=q1_answer)
```