# Flask view function losing request arguments when sending a POST request after GET request

Tags: python, http, flask, flask-login

This view receives the ?next= argument when making a GET request but once the user makes a POST request to the same view the argument is lost. The examples I've seen don't explicitly pass on the query arguments but seem to be able to retain them and get them in the following POST request.

```
@blueprint.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@logout_required()
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    #1
    print("NEXT:", request.args.get("next"))

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        u = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if u and u.check_password(password=form.password.data):
            if u.is_active():
                #2
                print("NEXT:", request.args.get("next"))

                login_user(u, remember=form.remember.data)

                next_url = request.args.get("next")
                if not next_url or url_parse(next_url).netloc != "":
                    next_url = url_for("main.index")

                return redirect(next_url)
            else:
                flash("This account has been disabled", "error")
        else:
            flash("Invalid password or username.", "error")

    return render_template("auth/login.html", form=form)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954122/how-can-i-pass-arguments-into-redirecturl-for-of-flask

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've managed to narrow down the issue coming from how I submit the POST request in the `<form>`. When I set the `<form>` action attribute to an empty string, it retains the original request arguments and passes them on to the view function. I'm not sure in what way it's doing this and wonder if there's an explicit way of setting the action to pass forward the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue was basically because I was mixing GET request arguments with POST input submissions.

for my login url `http://localhost:8000/auth/login?next=%2Fadmin`

```
<form action="">
```

will send a POST request to the login view function and allow access through `request.args.get()`

However, the proper way to capture and pass on the GET request `next` argument would be through a hidden input field that holds the initial GET request's `next` argument, allowing it to be passed properly as part of the form in the POST request.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('auth.login' }}">
    <input id="next" name="next" type="hidden" value="/admin">
```

The view function:

```
@blueprint.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@logout_required()
def login():
    form = LoginForm(next=request.args.get("next"))
```

Comment: For reference, I came across this issue following the Flask Mega Tutorial, part V to be specific. Didn't think changing the form action attribute would cause the behavior change on how the POST request passes on GET request arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing two redirections with `return redirect()` after last the two `flash()` functions, see the code below:

```
@blueprint.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@logout_required()
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    #1
    print("NEXT:", request.args.get("next"))

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        next_url = request.args.get("next")  #  -- HERE -- get "?next argument"

        u = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if u and u.check_password(password=form.password.data):
            if u.is_active():
                #2
                print("NEXT:", request.args.get("next"))

                login_user(u, remember=form.remember.data)

                # next_url = request.args.get("next")  # -- HERE -- 
                if not next_url or url_parse(next_url).netloc != "":
                    next_url = url_for("main.index")

                return redirect(next_url)

            else:
                flash("This account has been disabled", "error")
                return redirect(url_for('auth.index'))  # -- HERE --

        else:
            flash("Invalid password or username.", "error")
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login', next=next_url))  # -- HERE --

    return render_template("auth/login.html", form=form)
```

i assume `/main` is the protected route and there's currently no session, the user is **not logged in** yet, so when the user try to **directly** access

```
http://localhost:5000/admin
```

he will be automatically redirected to this `url` (`auth.login` route with an argument `?next=%2Fadmin%2F`)

```
http://localhost:5000/auth/login?next=%2Fadmin%2F
```

with the default `flask-login` `flash()` message `Please log in to access this page.` then he could login, if the login was successful he will be logged in and redirected to the protected area using `?next` argument,

but if it happens and the temptation fails, we have two options:

- if `Invalid password or username` he will be redirected the `auth.login` route **with** `?next=%2Fadmin%2F` argument for second chance.
- but if `This account has been disabled` he will be redirected the `auth.login` route **without** `?next=%2Fadmin%2F` argument and it does make sens.

and finally your don't need to worry about the value of `?next=` because the user could play with it or even remove it and this block

```
                if not next_url or url_parse(next_url).netloc != "":
                    next_url = url_for("main.index")

                return redirect(next_url)
```

defaults to `main.index` if any.

Comment: That's not the issue I'm having. Those flashes pass through and re-render the template, acting as a redirect to the same view function.

Comment: `flash()` doesn't perform **redirections**,  you need add them explicitly, just try the code and then let see.

Comment: I know `flash()` doesn't perform redirections. In this case I want the user to reload onto the same view with the flashed messages which is achieved through the final `render_template()` on the function. The second `redirect()` you added would be no difference in behavior to what is happening now and the first `redirect()` you added is not where I want them to be redirected.

Comment: i updated my answer and let me know if that's exactly what you want. i marked updated lines with `-- HERE --`

Comment: Your first change `next_url = request.args.get("next")  #  -- HERE -- get "?next argument"` is what I was originally having problems with as it was getting lost on the POST request. I've put up the solution I found to the problem. It also deals with the issue of losing the ?next argument as it is preserved within a hidden field.